# using lp_solve with visual studio 2015

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, lpsolve

I'm rather new to C++. I'm trying to use VS2015 and the lp_solve library(https://sourceforge.net/projects/lpsolve/files/lpsolve/5.5.2.5/) to solve my linear eq problem(for exact Gromov-Hausdorrf Distance, see https://mediatum.ub.tum.de/doc/1231885/1231885.pdf section 3.1 and 3.3). My machine is x64 system. Here is what I've done:

- donwload the lp_solve_5.5.2.5_dev_win64.zip package and decompress it.
- specific the library directoy(through project -> properties -> linker)
- specific lib I used (liblpsolve55.lib and liblpsolve55d.lib for statically linking) through project->properties->linker->input->additional dependency.
- declare the .h file directory(through project->properties->C/C++).
- Here is what I declare in my code:

  `#include "lp_lib.h"`

  `#pragma comment(lib, "liblpsolve55.lib") // static`

  `#pragma comment(lib, "liblpsolve55d.lib") // static for debug`

While when I run the code with x86, it will show the following problems:

- error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _make_lp@8 referenced in function "void __cdecl my_solve [totally 13 errors like this]
- warning LNK4272: library machine type 'X86' conflicts with target machine type 'x64' [totally 2 warnings like this]

While when I switch the runner with x64:

- I got 550 errors, mainly due to the “dlfcn.h”: No such file or directory
- in the lp_lib.h file, it has lines:

  ```
  #if (LoadInverseLib == TRUE) || (LoadLanguageLib == TRUE)
    #ifdef WIN32
      #include <windows.h>
    #else
      #include <dlfcn.h>
    #endif
  #endif
  ```
- which means it has treat me as a linux machine since dlfcn.h is for unix/linux

I've also try to use the 32bit version package(lp_solve_5.5.2.5_dev_win32.zip), but it do not work either.

- with x86 runner:__iob, _printf issues.
- with x64 runner:“dlfcn.h”: No such file or directory

I've successively build and run the demo in my mac with the corresponding package(lp_solve_5.5.2.5_dev_osx32.tar.gz). **But I still want to know how to build and run it in VS2015.**

Here I'll state what I do in mac if anyone need it(using Xcode).

- download the lp_solve_5.5.2.5_dev_osx32.tar.gz package
- add all the .h file in build phase -> headers
- add the liblpsolve55.a file in build phase -> link binary with libraries
- (if you want to use .dylib as dynamic linking, add it to the build phase -> copy file, but it do not work for me)
- in build setting, set the *Architectures* to 32-bit intel
- in build setting, set the *Build Active Architecture Only* to No

**Thank you very much, actually nobody answer this question :)  But I've solve the problem myself. Here is what I do for VS2015:**

- use package lp_solve_5.5.2.5_dev_win32.zip
- add the .h file and .lib as above
- change the run library, through properties -> C/C++ -> code generation -> run library -> change the DLL(/MDd) to (/MTd)
- if you still got some fprintf issues, go to properties -> linker -> input -> additional dependency, and add : legacy_stdio_definitions.lib

That will be OK. That my be some translation issue, yes I use the chinese-version VS...